# Error al usar OpenCV o pytesseract en python OSX

Tags: python, opencv, pytesseract

Estoy tratando de extraer el texto de una imagen con pytesseract.

Pero me da el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pytesseract-master/tests/test_pytesseract.py", line 29, in <module>
    test_quick_brown_dog_image()
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pytesseract-master/tests/test_pytesseract.py", line 17, in test_quick_brown_dog_image
    assert 'The quick brown dog' in image_to_string(test_file, 'eng')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 309, in image_to_string
    }[output_type]()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 308, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 218, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 194, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractError(status_code, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file /opt/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'eng\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')
```

He estado viendo que hace falta definir el path del idioma, y me gustaria que funcionara tanto el ingles como el español.

He probado a hacer el wget y añadir el `eng.traineddata` en el directorio que me dice, pero me dice lo mismo.

Trabajo sobre macos, alguien me podria indicar que he de hacer?

El codigo con el que trabajo es el propio test de ithub de pytesseract.

https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract

Gracias anticipado.

Comment: ¿Te has descargado los los lenguajes desde https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata y lo has colocado en el directorio?

Comment: Y agregaría, tienes `tesseract` instalado? Has configurado su ubicación mediante: `tessdata_dir_config = r'--tessdata-dir "<replace_with_your_tessdata_dir_path>"'`?

Comment: Gracias, es lo que me faltaba, en principio me funciona correctamente por ahora. Voy a hacer unas pruebas.